# What is this strange character in chrome's resource css viewer?

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]

This little bugger here caused me quite a headache. 
It doesn't appear at the end of the css file, but stays there after that bracket. Anything after that stops running. I was wondering why a lot of code wasn't running. I decided to move the code around.

Where does it come from? And Why?

I don't want to delete it until I replicate how it got there.

Thank you.

Comment: look at the file in a hex editor.

Comment: You could use `xxd` or `od` or `hexdump` to discover the values of those bytes; once you know those, you stand a chance of figuring out what put them in your file.

Comment: @SiGanteng, he said that nothing after that part runs, so it’s not something that can just be ignored.

Comment: Is it there for other CSS files or only that one? Is the CSS file really big or have really long lines?

Comment: No it's really your every day css code I would say. My code is not that different from others. Oh well I've decided to give up on this. Thank you for trying... I think this just beyond my reach.

Answer (score 2):

That's what you get when you look at an UTF-8 encoded SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201B) with an editor that thinks it's Windows-1252.

And it stops running because it's an error in CSS. The browser ignores everything that's an error.

Comment: No idea, it's not like this is a normal "smart quote", so you can't just type it in, unless you try really hard.

Comment: One way of getting the ‘smart quote’ without trying hard is to use MS Word, with document language set to English, and type the Ascii apostrophe ('). Word will auto-correct it to smart opening quote (‘), or (depending on content) to smart closing quote. Some other programs do such ‘corrections’, too.

Comment: But that's not it! Like I said, this is not a normal smart quote. MS-Word only produces U+2018 U+2019 U+201C and 201D.