# CSS Won't work Unless Rule Set is Repeated

Tags: css

I have two classes, left and right, that float and clear things left and right (real crazy stuff).

But here's the problem.

```
.dashWrap h3 {
background-color: #666;
border: 2px solid #000;
/*border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0;*/
text-indent: 0.5em;
}

.dashWrap .dashContent {
/* max-height: 5em;*/
min-height:5em;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
border: 2px solid #000;
border-top-color: transparent;
}​

.right  //If I delete or comment this out, left no longer is applied to anything.
{
clear:right;
float:right;
width:35%;
}
.left
 {
float:left;
clear:left;
 }
.right  //If I delete or comment out this, right no longer is applied to anything.
 {
clear:right;
float:right;
width:35%;
 }
```

That's the exact section I have in the file I am editing.  the only difference in the actual source file when I load the website is that after the closing curly for .dashContent, there is this :

**â€‹**

What could be causing this?

Comment: remove overflow-x: hidden or set it on auto.

Comment: Can you show what is the problem, need to see the source code. Please provide a link.

Comment: @Subhajit: The source code is already posted here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this strange character in chrome's resource css viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859326/what-is-this-strange-character-in-chromes-resource-css-viewer)

Comment: I was asking for the link where that character is displaying

Comment: Character wasn't displaying anything, it was just in the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some invisible or corrupted characters in you file, so the first rule after the .dashContent will be broken and is ignored by the browser.

Try to delete everything between the rules to get rid of the invisible characters, and if that fails you can try copying the rules into a new file. If all else fails, you may have to retype part of the file.

Comment: You were right.  I copied the problem code into Notepad++ and, what do you know, there was a question mark at where the mystery character was showing up.  I deleted that and pasted it back in and it's all fixed.  Not sure where it came from but it's gone now, thank you.